# Using scons to compile c++ file with -std=c++11 flag

Tags: c++11, scons

I am trying to compile a c++ file with -std=c=+11 option using scons.

File : test.cc

```
#include <unordered_map>

int foo()
{ return 0; }
```

File : SConstruct

```
env = Environment()
env.Append(CXXFLAGS = '-std=c++11')
#print env['CXXFLAGS']

src_files = Split('test.cc')
lib_name = 'test'

Library(lib_name, src_files)
```

I am getting the following error.  It seems CXXFLAGS is not taking effect when g++ is invoked:

```
g++ -o test.o -c test.cc
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/unordered_map:35:0,
                 from test.cc:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
 #error This file requires compiler and library support for the \
  ^
scons: *** [test.o] Error 1
```

I have read a few postings about compiling c++ files with -std=c++11 option by modifying the "Construction Environment", which I feel I have done.  Can someone please help.

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `env.Library` instead of `Library` to build the library with your construction environment.

```
env = Environment()
env.Append(CXXFLAGS = '-std=c++11')

src_files = Split('test.cc')
lib_name = 'test'

env.Library(lib_name, src_files)
```

Comment: That worked, thank you very much.  What is the difference between "Library" and "env.Library".  Does the latter use a different "Construction Environment" (aka the one I instantiated and modified)?

Comment: Correct. Library uses the default environment, while env.Library (or generally env._Builder_, uses the environment _env_.